# How to have different dependencies depending on OS family

Tags: windows, unix, rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

I'm writing a cross-platform library that has platform specific dependencies, one for unix-like platforms, and one for windows. These crates only compile on specific platforms, wherefore I can't just add them all under dependencies normally.

In the actual rust code I use `cfg` attributes, like `#[cfg(unix)]` to compile certain code for certain platforms, and I want to do something similar in the Cargo.toml, or in a build script, for the dependencies. Currently, I'm using target triplets like these:

```
[target.i686-unknown-linux-gnu.dependencies.crate1]
git = repo1
[target.x86-unknown-linux-gnu.dependencies.crate1]
git = repo1
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.dependencies.crate1]
git = repo1

[target.i686-pc-windows-gnu.dependencies]
crate2 = "*"
[target.x86-pc-windows-gnu.dependencies]
crate2 = "*"
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.dependencies]
crate2 = "*"
```

However, this list is far from exhaustive. I don't care about architecture or ABI, only OS family, and as such, the list would get very long, were I to match for every single unix-like target triple.

Is there any way to use specific dependencies, determined only by the OS family of the platform cargo is run on? Something like:

```
[target.family.unix.dependencies]
abc-sys = "*"
def = "*"

[target.family.windows.dependencies]
abc-win = "*"
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As far as I read the docs [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies), this should now work:

```
[target.'cfg(unix)'.dependencies]
abc-sys = "*"
def = "*"

[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
abc-win = "*"
```

Comment: For those who want to do this based on architecture, this is how you do it: `target.'cfg(target_arch = "x86_64")'.dependencies`. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies

Answer (score 3):

```
# macos dependencies

[target.'cfg(target_os = "macos")'.dependencies]
dep1 = "*"
dep2 = "*"

# windows dependencies

[target.'cfg(target_os = "windows")'.dependencies]
dep3 = "*"
dep4 = "*"

# regular dependencies

[dependencies] 
dep5 = "*"
dep6 = "*"
```

Answer (score -1):

There currently is no way to do this. It would be nice, for sure.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. Please see **@Andrew Straw**'s answer.