# Why does the last platform-specific dependency take precedence in Cargo?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a dependency in my Cargo file that needs to be different by platform, specifically, the default features. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
[package]
name = "..blah.."
version = "..blah.."
authors = ["..blah.."]

[target.'cfg(target_os = "macos")'.dependencies]
hyper = { version = "0.9", default-features = false, features = ["security-framework"] }

[target.'cfg(target_os = "linux")'.dependencies]
hyper = { version = "0.9", default-features = true }
```

But this doesn't seem to do what I want. On my Mac it appears to be using the bottom target line as if I just specified `hyper = "0.9"`. If I do `cargo build` as specified, I get errors with regard to openssl:

> cargo:warning=#include <openssl/ssl.h>

However, if I build it like this:

```
[dependencies]
hyper = { version = "0.9", default-features = false, features = ["security-framework"] }
```

Then it builds fine. This indicates to me that the `cfg` for "macos" isn't working.

How do I make this work, or more specifically, how do I solve the problem where I need my dependency to use different features by platform?

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29854912/155423?

Comment: I guess it is not a duplicate because the syntax above seems to match the examples in the [unit tests](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/master/tests/cfg.rs) and [commit](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/2328/commits/f5d786e05600720ba4671caf5b598624103c8f72).

Comment: @Shepmaster well in theory they are trying to solve the same problem, so I suppose my question then is "Why isn't my Cargo file selecting the right configuration for a dependency".

Comment: @wimh I don't think I'm following. The [unit tests you linked to say](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/4f57637fbeb9a79c86808609e388a1eed9a50e2f/tests/cfg.rs#L152) `[target."cfg(windows)".dependencies]`, **without** `target_os`. The [documentation likewise does not use `target_os`](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html#platform-specific-dependencies).

Comment: @Shepmaster [here](https://github.com/alexcrichton/curl-rust/blob/master/Cargo.toml) is an example which uses `target_os`, although in a `not`. The configurations should be the same as used in `#[cfg(...)]`, where `target_os` is listed in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#conditional-compilation).

Comment: I'm suffering from the same issue… did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @lunaryorn nope. I've been meaning to file an issue on the Cargo GitHub repository.

Comment: @vcsjones I think it's a bug, so it'd be great if you could open an issue!  If you do could you CC me?  I've got the same username on Github.

Comment: Doesn't MacOS contain a Linux shell? I believe the Linux dependency is overriding the MacOS dependency by coming later in the list. Try swapping the dependencies around.

Answer (score 1):

It does not look like it is possible with Rust 1.13.0 and Cargo 0.13.0-nightly. See Cargo issues [3195](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3195) and [1197](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1197).

As a workaround, you can [tell Cargo to use Homebrew's OpenSSL](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/255#issuecomment-257462451):

```
export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=`brew --prefix openssl`/include
export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=`brew --prefix openssl`/lib
export DEP_OPENSSL_INCLUDE=`brew --prefix openssl`/include
```

Comment: Using Homebrew's OpenSSL is also documented [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34612395/155423), but I don't think that will help OP. Specifically, I believe they wish to *avoid using OpenSSL* on macOS, and use the built-in SSL framework instead.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it was not possible for the moment and that the rest was a workaround. For my use case, I prefer my crate to compile without manual modifications to `Cargo.toml` rather than commenting/uncommenting a line in it to link against the framework... Bu tI agree it's not optimal and does not solve the issue.